# Rails date mask jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Doğum Tarihi</label>
     <div class="input-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i>
        <%= f.text_field :birthdate, :required => true, class: 'form-control placeholder-no-fix', :id => "date", :placeholder => "Birth date" %>
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have text field on my form, in this form I used date mask --/--/----, the problem is when I write date such as 18/20/3333, it saves, how can I set rules form this mask. For example, day first '--' between 1-31, second '--' between 1-12, and last part between 1900-2020.

```
   $('#date').mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"-"});
```

Comment: Can you add some information, eg links to the documentation, for the jquery plugin you are using here?

Comment: (function(a){var b=(a.browser.msie?"paste":"input")+".mask",c=window.orientation!=undefined;a.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},dataName:"rawMaskFn"},a.fn.extend({caret:function(a,b){if(this.length!=0){if(typeof a=="number")

Comment: If that's a reply to my comment then it's not what i was asking for.  I was asking you to add a url for the documentation page of the `mask` plugin.